# Awkward: Combine two awk statements

Tags: awk, separator

I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
foo:123 bar baz
oof:2983 rab zdo 
mor:8 eoinn uiemdh
```

and what I'd like to have as result is:

```
123
2983
8
```

Assuming the data is in a file called test.txt, what I currently have is:

```
 awk '{print $1}' test.txt | awk -F: '{print $2}'
```

How can I combine those two statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could sed the field separator to a regex:

```
awk -F' |:' '{print $2}' file
123
2983
8
```

Comment: Ack! I forgot about regexes in field statements! I retract my "you can't" statement....

Comment: Didn't know that was possible. This is sweet!

Comment: Regex as a field separator is a gnu extension (cc @carveone)

Comment: `nawk` and `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` (solaris) can handle regex field separators, so not just `gawk`.

Comment: Can also be written as a character class: `-F '[ :]'`

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, you can't. But you can use the extensive pattern matching facilities to do what you want:

```
awk '{ tmp = $1; sub(/^.*:/, "", tmp); print tmp; }' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A short `awk`

```
awk -F' |:' '{$0=$2}1' file
123
2983
8
```

Comment: That will drop lines where the numeric value happens to be zero.